# oracle sql injection from web

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, code-injection

I am wanting to test for sql injection in my oracle app. Is there a way to inject some input to do some malicious act in the following basic scenario:

I have a basic form that calls a basic procedure to insert a record. I want to make sure it can not be sql injected. If so an example so that I can test.

```
<form action='insert_rec'>
  User name: <input type="text" name="p_name"><br>
  Password: <input type="text" name="p_pswd"><br>
</form>

create or replace procedure insert_rec(p_name varchar2(10), p_pswd varchar2(10));
begin
    insert into user_table
    (name,pswd)
    values
    (p_name,p_pswd);
end;
```

Comment: And how are you calling the stored procedure?

Comment: <form action='insert_rec'>